# IERC20 safeTransfer sender issue

Tags: solidity, tokens, transfer

0

I need to transfer some amount of an especific token (100) when the "father"(TTDT01) token is used.It is some kind of tax on a "child" token (ttdttoken) when the "father" token is used.
First I'm trying to make the transfer of the "child" token calling a function when a transfer is made , but I get an error "not enough balance" ,  I have checked that the transfer is trying to be made from the "father" token contract address , not from the user who interacts with the  father "token", who should be the owner of the "father" token...

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

contract TokenA {

    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

 
    IERC20 ttdttoken = IERC20(0x762a0Ce3D24Ea4Fe5bB3932e15Dd2BD87F894F98);
    address public receiver = 0xE6057bA67838dE723AA46c861F6F867f26FE09c4;
    string public name; // Holds the name of the token
    string public symbol; // Holds the symbol of the token
    uint8 public decimals; // Holds the decimal places of the token
    uint256 public totalSupply; // Holds the total suppy of the token
    address public owner; // Holds the owner of the token
    address public holder;

        

       /* This creates a mapping with all balances */
   mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    /* This creates a mapping of accounts with allowances */
   mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;


   event Transfer(address  owner,address receiver,uint256 tokens);



    constructor() {

        name = "TestTokenDT01"; // Sets the name of the token, i.e Ether
        symbol = "TTDT01"; // Sets the symbol of the token, i.e ETH
        decimals = 18; // Sets the number of decimal places
        uint256 _initialSupply = 1000000000 * 10 ** 18; // Holds an initial supply of coins

        /* Sets the owner of the token to whoever deployed it */
        owner = msg.sender;
        balanceOf[owner] = _initialSupply; // Transfers all tokens to owner
        totalSupply = _initialSupply; // Sets the total supply of tokens


         
        

    }


   function deposit() public {

      uint256 balanceERC20receiver = ttdttoken.balanceOf(receiver);
      uint256 balanceERC20owner = ttdttoken.balanceOf(owner);
      uint256 tokens = 100;
    
      balanceERC20receiver +=  tokens;
      balanceERC20owner -= tokens; 


       ttdttoken.safeTransfer(receiver, tokens);

    }
 

   function transfer(address _receiver, uint256 _tokens) public {

       this.deposit();

    }
 }
```